# Is there any way to do performance testing on website built on react js using Jmeter without selenium integration?

Tags: jmeter

I want to perform load test on website built on react js with 500 users.
Is it possible with jmeter without selenium plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can create JMeter test plans and simulate the 500 concurrent users accessing the system.

1. Record the test script
2. Correlate the session variables
3. Add timers
4. Configure the thread group
5. Run the test

There are a number of ways to build a JMeter test plan. You can use HTTPS [Test Script Recorder](https://youtu.be/gywvIasl0qU) or [Blazemeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) to record the steps. Then you will have to add [timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers), correlate the sessions with the JMeter post-processors, etc to simulate the real users.

[Ten ways to build your JMeter test plans](http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2021/10/20/jmeter-building-test-scripts/)

In your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) set the `Number of Threads (users)` to 500 to simulate 500 concurrent users. Add a ramp-up time (e.g 60 seconds).

Note: Timers will simulate the think time of the users or the delays between the requests. You may use [Random Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Gaussian_Random_Timer) to simulate different think times.

Answer (score 0):

It is, JMeter doesn't know/care anything about the system under test technology so as long as JMeter supports [network protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) used by the application it should be able to replicate the network footprint of the real browser.

Browsers in their turn don't do any magic, they send [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), wait for responses and render the response in the browser window.

JMeter is capable of sending HTTP requests via [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler so it can load test web applications, including but not limited to react js ones.

Just don't forget to [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser):

1. Configure HTTP Request samplers to retrieve embedded resources (images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc.) from web pages
2. Use [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to simulate browser cache
3. Use [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to simulate browser cookies
4. Use [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to simulate browser headers
5. Use [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) to simulate real user "think times" (real users don't hammer the website non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations, read something, type something, etc.)